# Экранирорвать $

Tags: linux, bash

Пытаюсь занести в файл  `$1` таким образом

`echo -e "$1 \n $1" > ~/ar.sh` 
$1 как я понимаю, воспринимается в качестве переменной
как можно экранировать данный символ?

Comment: Также как и `\n` - `\$`

Comment: Либо заключить в одинарные кавычки